# How to sound-proof glass door with everyday things?

Tags: sound, indoor

Not sure if this is question for this part of SE.

Anyway, how would you sound proof a door that is made just with wood frame and a sheet of glass 5 milimeters thick? 
I got to some ideas like Egg crates but that is too tall to fit properly in the space available. I could cut it but it would look ugly.

Another idea I got is bottle caps, but that way I have to buy lot of bottles to cover the whole area.

Here are some images I made of my door. The glass is covered with wood-lookalike duck-tape.

[image: glass door 1]

[image: glass door 2]

As you can see from the second image the frame has space which is 2-2.5 centimeters deep.The Egg crate is about 6 centimeters tall.

Any ideas are welcome.

I got inspiration by NASA soundless room:

[image: NASA soundless room]

Comment: How about CD Jewel cases? :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_disc_packaging

Comment: Do you have a target STC? Also what kind of construction limits are you working with? Owning or renting this space? Can you do stuff like install an additional door, etc? I suppose the answer to your question is, "It can't be done with everyday things".

Comment: Its the room where I live. On the other side is the phone, so people on the other side cannot talk without been heard by me, which is stupid. I also cannot sleep whn the TV in the other room is on :) what is STC?

Comment: I though if I glue an array of CD cases they will break the sound traveling trought the door in diff. directions, therefore preventing it to come clearly into the other room.

Comment: Sound Transmission Class. The, um, CD case array might act as a diffuser (bouncing the sound all around) but very high frequencies but it will do basically nothing to stop sound from going right through. Tetsujin is spot on when he says mass is the only thing that actually stops sound from going from point A to point B. Hanging some heavy drapes behind the door that you can part as you enter and leave might help. So... you live someplace with an actual land line? Weird. ;-)

Comment: Its a normal phone line. What's strange about it? The strangest thing is why did the idiot interior designer put glass door between living and a sleeping room.

Comment: And of course I don't expect to be 100% sound proof. Probably will try the CD case idea.

Comment: If your room doesn't have both a closet and a window then you can let the interior designer off the hook because your room wasn't meant to be a bedroom. A lot of people just use their mobile phones these days so I'm not used to thinking of actual phones lines outside of businesses. Good luck with the jewel cases, I wish I thought they would help.

Comment: BTW, the NASA room might look a little bit like egg boxes... but is actually stunningly expensive acoustic foam, inside several thousand tons of concrete box & room-within-room isolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with soundproofing glass doors is that there has to be two layers of glass with a little space in between the two to properly soundproof it.

One of the comments i saw up there said CD Jewel Cases might work... im thinking that would be the best option aside from installing double thick glass in that doorway. Also make sure that you fill ANY SPACES AROUND THE DOOR with rubber or pug or anything that fits in there. It makes more sense to install something like rubber compressors or fiberglass around the frame than filling it every single time you close the door.

Other solutions are sound proofed doors (expensive), a heavy fire door with rubber compression seals around the frame or installing a "sound lobby" (a hallway with another door) so there are two doors between one side of the wall and the other.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to soundproof anything is **mass**.

You need weight. Nothing else will work for bass frequencies.
No amount of egg boxes will have any effect.

Assuming you actually still need access to the door & that rebuilding the entire thing triple-glazed is right out of the question, then the only thing I can think of might be lots of heavy blankets, floor to ceiling.

It's either that or a half ton of concrete ;-)

Comment: Not really gonna do what you say here, but anyway thanks for the advice.

Comment: Hi Vlad, Tetsujin is right. You cannot expect anything else to work. The cd jewel case is a bad idea for soundproofing. Oh and since you're relatively new here, next time someone gives an answer that has been upvoted, please be a little gentler instead of saying 'Not really gonna do what you say'. He's not telling you to do as he says, he's merely giving advice. No biggie, just trying to keep everyone happy.

Comment: The concrete idea seamed silly to me :) I had no bad intentions, though. No offence. But yes this proves that I souldn't bothering at all with the door. Just put new thicker one.

Answer (score 1):

Weight. Heavy fiberglass. a heavy mattress maybe(??). Things that are heavy with a lot of surface area.

Another thing to note is thickness. The thickness of an object will tell you what wavelengths it will dissipate. That's why you always hear the bass from next door's stereo, because the wavelength is longer than the depth of the wall.

p.s. egg boxes are for room reverberance, to stop getting dead spots and such.

FYI the best soundproofing would be a solid steel door, a few inches thick, and around the room, a pocked of vacuum space.